# Android onDraw method

Tags: android, animation, canvas

in the onDraw(Canvas canvas1) method i see how it is possible to draw shapes using the passed argument of "canvas1". However, if i were to create a new Canvas object example":

```
Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

canvas2.drawRect(55,87,130,600, paint);
```

canvas2 won't be displayed on screen, how can i get it displayed together with the canvas1 object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to draw layers? Perhaps you need to use a viewgroup such as [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) with two children views: one using canvas1, the other using canvas2.

Answer (score 0):

When you create canvas using `Canvas()` constructor, your get an empty raster canvas. 
As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas%28%29):

> Construct an empty raster canvas. Use setBitmap() to specify a bitmap to draw into.

This means that your drawings are just thrown away unless you explicitly attach bitmap to `Canvas` object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using custom ImageViews rendered in a FrameLayout as I explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792331/sluggish-zoom-and-scroll-with-gridview-in-android).