# custom android.app.Application not firing onCreate event

Tags: java, android, events

I'm deriving a custom application from android.app.Application and I can't get its onCreate event being fired. Here's the implementation

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm using it:

```
MyApplication ctrl = new MyApplication();
```

Comment: `ctrl.onCreate();` will do it for you ...

Comment: Yes, it does. But shouldn't this be fired automatically? I can call onCreate() in the constructor as well but I don't think this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: you should call MyApplication constructor at all... you should point this class in manifest xml and Android OS should call it ... and onCreate too

Comment: And how should I declare an Application called from an Activity in the AndroidManifest? By default an application tag is already added there.

Comment: why you need to extends standard Application class ...

Comment: To be able to create and object from which I can call methods and modify properties. Using Intent to create such object instances didn't allow me to do that.

Comment: for global variables ? ... not a good idea ... what you wana achive with this ?

Comment: No, not global variables, object properties and methods. My optimal solution would be what I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792331/sluggish-zoom-and-scroll-with-gridview-in-android. However, due to this issue I can't follow this approach until I find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Add following in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</application>
```

then your `onCreate()` will get fired.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have the main Activity defined as an application by the fault at AndroidManifest.xml and this additional application tag. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @BalajiKhadake My app class extends from a library application class and onCreate in library doesn't fired!

Comment: Must add class name to android:name, like android:name="your.package.com.MyApplication".

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue and found that in my case that the whole issue was phone side.  I rebooted the phone and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Dude. You potentially saved me hours with this answer. Thanks.

Comment: it is true that it is phone specific problem, but restarting the device did not solve the problem in my case.

Answer (score 4):

**Very simple**

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, within the `application` tag enter the name of your `Application` sub-class with it's path under the `android:name` attribute.

**Example:**

```
<application
...
android:name=".models.custom.BaseApplication"
...
> ... </application>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually create instances of your Activities with the `new`operator. Instead you start an Intent like this:

```
Intent start = new Intent(context, Classname.class);
context.startActivity(start);
```

When creating an object with the `new` operator, then `onCreate` never will be called.

[EDIT] When creating Applications with the `new` operator `onCreate` won't be called either[/EDIT]

[EDIT2] You could create a static method that returns the application like this:

```
public static MyApplication getApp() {
    return mInstance;
}
```

[/EDIT2]

Comment: it's not Activity it's Application

Comment: oops, my bad. But that also applies to an Application. If you create your application with the new operator, onCreate won't be called.

Comment: Yes, I did that but I need to be able to get object instance to be able to set object properties and call its methods.

Comment: you could create a static method that returns the singleton of this Application.

Comment: You cannot return *this* from a static method -_-

Answer (score 1):

Don't construct it, get it from `Context`.

For example from `Activity`:

```
MyApplication ctrl = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
```

More info:
[Context.getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)

Documentation says that `onCreate()` is

> Called when the application is starting, before any other application
>   objects have been created

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Actually the application crashes at this line.

Comment: The line you suggested: MyApplication ctrl = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317

Comment: Thanks. The problem here is that I should also declare that application at AndroidManifest.xml but, according to Balaji's reply and comments, I can't have 2 applications defined there. Can you think of a solution to this?

Comment: @NarcísCalvet it not getApplicationContext() its activityInstance.getApplication()

Comment: @Diljeet, that was on 2011 and I'm no longer working in this project neither developing for Android anymore..

Answer (score 1):

In Manifest file  Make sure u have added the tag i.e class which extends Application.

**Tag= android:name=".MyApplication**

**ManifestFile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.services">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Services">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--Declaring the Service in the manifest file-->
        <service
            android:name=".MyServiceDemo"
            android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

***MyApplication.java(i.e class which extends Applicatoin)***

```
package com.example.services;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyAppsNotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        notificationManager = MyAppsNotificationManager.getInstance(this);
        notificationManager.registerNotificationChannelChannel(
                getString(R.string.channelId),
                "BackgroundService",
                "BackgroundService");
    }

    public static MyAppsNotificationManager getMyAppsNotificationManager(){
        return notificationManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Balaji Mentioned if your still facing issue even after mentioning class name under application tag

```
<application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"> </application>
```

Then try this:

**Try and disabling Instant Run** and then clean project and Rebuild it and then run again.
It worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I needed to **log** something and it wasn't called `Application` `onCreate()`.

> If you have the same problem and need some `Side Effects` to trigger like `Analytics` events.
> Use these 2 approaches.
>
> Don't put your main logic **(for example don't initialize the libraries)**
> in the below places.

`Approach 1:` Override `onCreate` of your `Application` Class like below:

```
     @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
     override fun onCreate() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
          ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.withCreated {
            // Here onCreate of the Application will be called !
          }
        }
        super.onCreate()
      }
```

`Approach 2:` Create a class for example named AppLifecycleListener that implements `DefaultLifecycleObserver` and override required methods.

```
@Singleton
class AppLifecycleListener @Inject constructor() : DefaultLifecycleObserver {

override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onCreate(owner)
    // Here onCreate of the Application will be called !
   }
}
```

Don't forget to `addObserver()` your class in `Application`

```
@Inject
lateinit var appLifecycleListener: AppLifecycleListener

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(appLifecycleListener)
}
```