# Using microsoft face recognition services faceServiceClient is getting null (using same code snippet as in documentation and sample app)

Tags: android, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

> using following code snippet to find similar faces via asynch task

```
class DetectionTask extends AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Face[]> {
        private boolean mSucceed = true;
        int mRequestCode;
        DetectionTask(int requestCode) {
            mRequestCode = requestCode;
        }

        @Override
        protected Face[] doInBackground(InputStream... params) {

            FaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = SampleApp.getFaceServiceClient();

            try{
                publishProgress("Detecting...");

                // Start detection.
                return faceServiceClient.detect(
                        params[0],  /* Input stream of image to detect */
                        true,       /* Whether to return face ID */
                        false,       /* Whether to return face landmarks */
                        /* Which face attributes to analyze, currently we support:
                           age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair */
                        null);
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                mSucceed = false;
                publishProgress(e.getMessage());
                addLog(e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

> using this following class to generate a Face service client
>   This is my code for Sample App

```
public class SampleApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sFaceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient(getString(R.string.subscription_key));
    }

    public static FaceServiceClient getFaceServiceClient() {
        return sFaceServiceClient;
    }

    private static FaceServiceClient sFaceServiceClient;
}
```

> While debugging I found that sFaceServiceClient is always null when
>   calling SampleApp.getFaceServiceClient() so I don't get any response
>   due to null object . I tried using different keys via multiple
>   accounts but of no help . The same issue still persists. A help will be appreciated

Comment: The obvious question is whether `SampleApp.onCreate` is being called or not.  Can you confirm?  If not, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858158/custom-android-app-application-not-firing-oncreate-event

Comment: @cthrash : thanks a lot very silly mistake . It worked  seamlessly